# Javascript Promise works between script tags, but gets rejected when pasted in console

Tags: javascript, async-await, promise, console

The following script, simply chains XHR promises and awaits for a response(resolve or reject) before sending out the next.

The script **works as intended** when presented between  tags in a separate .html file but fails (promise gets rejected) when I paste it in the browser(latest chrome).

Questions: What is happening? Can I make changes so it could run from console?

```
function retrieve(url){
    return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onload = () => resolve(xhr.response);
    xhr.onerror = () => reject("request failed "+xhr.response)
    xhr.open('GET', url)
    xhr.send();
    });
};

const n = 50;
const url = 'https://random.dog/woof.json'

async function asyncTask() {
    for (let i=0;i<n;i++){
        console.log(i+1)
        console.log(await retrieve(url))
    }
};
asyncTask();
```

Edit:
As suggested in the comments, the `asyncTask().catch(err=>console.log(err)` gives `net::ERR_FAILED`

Also tested the script with different urls including some XML specific ones,
all return the same error:
`GET https://demo.autodns.com/gateway/ net::ERR_FAILED`

Comment: Rate-limiter, maybe?

Comment: Try `asyncTask().catch(err=>console.log(err)` instead of `asyncTask()` to see if it reports the rejection reason.

Comment: @trakt
Edited the post to reflect this test: it returned `net::ERR_FAILED`

Comment: Since the requesting URL in another origin, you have to handle CORS

Comment: @PranavanJegatheeswaran I was just about to comment that i've also tested with a site that allows CORS `https://evilinsult.com/generate_insult.php?lang=en&type=json`
it returned the same result. Do I need to change my request?

Comment: @amitsrourdev I've just copied and pasted your above code in my console. It worked for me. Navigate to network tab, and see weather this is caused by anti-virus

Comment: @PranavanJegatheeswaran did you used the console in the same page as the url?
try opening a new tab and paste the script.
I tested it from various computers/networks.

Comment: @amitsrourdev What do you mean by "new tab"? You cannot run scripts in empty tabs.